# Windows services's OnStop() method does not get called

Tags: c#, logging, windows-services

I have written a Windows service in C# to log all user logons and logoffs, and save them in a table on a server.

I have used a `while` loop with `true` condition and check the system's current user every minute in this loop, so my service goes to '**Starting**' status when i turn on my system.

Everything goes fine up to here, but the problem is that the `OnStop()` method does not get called when I shut down my system. I know that the problem is about the status of the service when it starts, because when I comment the `while` loop in my service's `OnStart()` method, the `OnStop()` method will get executed correctly.

Comment: I think the infinite while loop is the one contributing to the behaviour. Perhaps you should instead use a timer that fires after every 1 minute

Comment: I have used timer already (with timer control and also with code) but even the service did not start.In my large amount of searches i have found that the windows service has  some problems with timer and does not work with it.

Answer (score 4):

The OnStart (and OnStop) are not made to **not** finish - they are designed to initialize the service, and then finish. What I usually do is create a separate [thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx) (this was before the [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) was created), start the Thread, and done.

In your case, the thread would then start a timer, and wait for a stop signal, which could be sent from the OnStop method when the service stops. When the stop signal arrives, it should stop the timer.

Comment: Hi Maarten and thanks for your rapid reply. I have tried your solution but the OnStop() method did not do successfully.

Comment: I'm waiting for your reply yet,please help me.

Comment: What happens in the OnStop method? Is an exception thrown?

Comment: I have used OnSessionChange event to check and save the logons and logoffs and it works fine but when the system is shutting down that event does not fire for logoff,so i have tried to save this last logoff in shutdown event but it has problem(It does not thrown any exceptions)

Answer (score 3):

OnStart() must return the operating system, below is the MSDN documentation,

> A service application is designed to be long running. As such, it
>   usually polls or monitors something in the system. The monitoring is
>   set up in the OnStart method. However, OnStart does not actually do
>   the monitoring. The OnStart method **must return to the operating system**
>   once the service's operation has begun. **It must not loop forever or
>   block.**

---

> To set up a simple polling mechanism, you can use the
>   System.Timers.Timer component. In the OnStart method, you would set
>   parameters on the component, and then you would set the Timer.Enabled
>   property to true. The timer would then raise events in your code
>   periodically, at which time your service could do its monitoring.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984464%28v=vs.71%29.aspx