# windows service OnStop method

Tags: c#, .net

Are there guarantees that this method will be called when service is shut down? 
I want to implement some save state using serialization when service is stopped.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11389428/1218281

Comment: Does this help? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a.aspx

Comment: @RahulTripathi: please don't ever post .NET 1.1 links unless the question is about .NET 1.1.

Comment: @JohnSaunders:- Sorry for that. Updated the link!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: In short: no, there's no guarantee. For example as far as I can tell, if the user will terminate the service via the task manager --> Kill Process, or if the main thread will crash with unhandled error, the OnStop won't get called. You better save the state in fixed time intervals instead.